# ¿Que significa “selladas”?

Tags: significado, literatura

Estaba leyendo [*El amor en los tiempos del cólera*](https://www.wattpad.com/456326612-el-amor-en-los-tiempos-del-c%C3%B3lera-cap%C3%ADtulo-1) de García Márquez y encontré esta frase:

> Las otras ventanas, así como cualquier resquicio de la habitación, estaban amordazadas con trapos o **selladas** con cartones negros, y eso aumentaba su densidad opresiva.

¿Qué significa ***selladas*** en este contexto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creo que "selladas" en este caso no es más que el participio de "[sellar](https://dle.rae.es/sellar?m=form)", que en una de sus acepciones significa

> 4. tr. Cerrar herméticamente algo.

El párrafo da a entender que las ventanas estaban tapiadas ([tapiar](https://dle.rae.es/tapiar?m=form): Cerrar un hueco haciendo en él un muro o un tabique. *Tapiar la puerta, la ventana*). El autor lo explica de manera un poco poética con "las ventanas y los resquicios estaban *amordazados*", pero "selladas con cartones" deja claro que se intentan tapar los huecos de la ventana que dejan pasar la luz.

Han **tapado** (o sellado) las ventanas o huecos en ellas para impedir el paso de la luz.

Answer (score 2):

En este contexto significa algo así como cerradas herméticamente, todo lo hermético que pueda ser el cartón, claro.